# Converting HTTP response json into typescript Object in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to create a typescript object from an HTTP response in angular8, But I receive an error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: Profile is not defined
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (app.service.ts:17)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:134)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:77)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:41)

My Profile.ts file is : [here](https://pastebin.com/7f5u7aCr)
My app.service.ts file is: [here](https://pastebin.com/kzV6Dyz4)

I construct a component class object with this service result and I also get the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

when I use it in the HTML file.

The console output for the statement in service file is:

```
{
  name: "somename",
  status: "sometext",
  bio: "sometext",
  email: "email",
  gitlab: "link",
  twitter: "link",
  instagram: "link",
  linkedin: "link",
  telegram: "link"

},
```

This is output accompanied by the errors.

My HTML code shortly is :

```
<p class="ui header">{{profile.name}}</p>
```

My component class file is: [here](https://pastebin.com/u6E7suep)

Comment: Adding an update to the above issue, Now, The console.log(this.profile) statement in service prints the data. But in the component, the data is not printed. I don't know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in `getProfile()` method of your `AppService`. You are returning `this.profile` from this method, instead, you should return an observable like this:

```
getProfile(): Observable<Profile> {
    return this.http.get(this.profileApiUrl) 
               .pipe(
                  map(pro => new Profile(pro))
               );
  }
```

Now in component inject this service in the component constructor like this:

```
//have a class variable
//this will be used in the template to render the profile
profile: Profile;
constructor(private _appService: AppService) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this._appService.getProfile().subscribe(pro => {this.profile = pro;});
}
```

Use a safe operator in the template -

```
<p class="ui header">{{profile?.name}}</p>
```

Comment: It didn't work, I tried your changes, produces an additional error, "Profile is not a constructor".

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan You have a constructor in your Profile class.

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan share your updated code; The code I shared works for me. It is some other issue.

Comment: The data are still not printed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195387/discussion-between-user2216584-and-sivaramakrishnan).

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan you need to use `export` keyword before `class Profile`

Comment: I did export the class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extra code to map to `Profile` object. HttpClient would do it for you.
You need to make few changes to service.ts as below:

```
getProfile(): Observable<Profile> {
    this.http.get<Profile>(this.profileApiUrl)
    .pipe(map((pro: any) =>{
      this.profile = pro;
      return pro
    });
  }
}
```

In Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this._appService.getProfile().subscribe(pro => this.profile = pro;);
}
```

And in you html:

```
<p class="ui header">{{profile?.name}}</p>
```